# Error en GitHub CLI al intentar usarlo

Tags: github, cli

tengo un error al intentar usar y ejecutar GH CLI en mi equipo.

Alguien le ha pasado? Tengo HighSierra 10.13 y he ejecutado bien los comandos, en mi caso

`gh user -l` introduzco mi nombre de usuario sin el arroba delante y el password copiado y pegado correctamente y me da un error.

[image: Error GitHub CLI terminal]